# response from soap envelop is 0

Tags: iphone, ipad, wsdl

```
2012-07-27 20:15:53.523 ProjectDemo[1697:40b] Done. received Bytes 0
2012-07-27 20:15:53.524 ProjectDemo[1697:40b] the xml Data is

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];
[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue:@"ManageCase" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

i am getting response from soap envelop is 0.

Can any one advice me for what cases the response will 0.

@thanks in advance

Comment: No we can't, because we are going to need more information. Is it a public soap service? What are you posting? stuuf like that.

Comment: @rckoenes  I can understand.  Its not public soap service! Can i know what information you need

Answer (score 1):

Try using "text/xml; charset=utf-8" for your Content-Type header field value.

Also try including your whole namespace as part of the SOAPAction header, E.g. "http://www.yournamespace.com/ManageCase"

Here's a SOAP 1.1 Objective-C code sample:

```
NSString *soapAction = @"Login";
NSString *messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [message length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serverURL];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.namespace.com/%@", soapAction] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request addValue:messageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: yeap i call the text/xml,  and change my name space and s